# Unable to to select 1 radioButton out of several in Fortran VisualStudio Project .rc-File

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, fortran, radio-button, resource-files

I am supposed to update a very old program written in Fortran which is set up as a Visual Studio Project using a .rc-File.

The old version of the program used a GUI having 2 radio-buttons `Var1` and `Var2` that could be selected( only one of them). Now I want to expand the GUI having 7 radio-buttons ( `var1`-`var7`) from which still only 1 should be able to be selected.

Since I have no Idea neither of Fortran nor of the rc-File-type I tried to do it like that:

[image]

having done that I get the following problem:
- the radiobuttons (`var1`-`var7`) are there and can be selected ( one at a time) which is fine
- Only when I press `Var1` or `Var2` (the old ones) the value-id of that button gets updated so that I can use these value for later use. `Var3`-`var7` don`t get updated.

**Does anybody know what I did wrong?**

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code, [edit] the question and copy the text. You have already some decent SO reputation ans some experience with this site so it shoulnd not be a problem for you.

Comment: Are you using Intel Visual Fortran or which kind of compiler? What kind GUI library do you use? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your code for something like GetDlgItem(IDC_GASVEL).  There probably aren't any for GetDlgItem(IDC_PRESS) .. GetDlgItem(IDC_IGSTR) as you have only added the entries in the resource (RC) file and not the code file.

to check whether the radio button is set, have a look at how IsChecked is used.  To set a button, use SetCheck